# Read data from an html stream using spring boot and feign

Tags: spring-boot, java-stream, feign

I'm developing two java applications, one is producer and other is consumer. I want to stablish an streaming connection between them.

I have two java web application, lets name them producer and consumer. The producer is responsible to write a stream of text in output. here is the producer code:

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletOutputStream
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*


@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/test")
class TestController {

    private val lines: List<String> = Arrays.asList(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
        "consectetur adipiscing elit,",
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    )

    @GetMapping(value = ["html"], produces = ["text/html"])
    @Throws(
        IOException::class, InterruptedException::class
    )
    fun getHtml(request: HttpServletRequest, response: ServletResponse) {
        render(Renderers.HTML, request, response)
    }

    @GetMapping(value = ["text"], produces = ["application/octet-stream"])
    @Throws(
        IOException::class, InterruptedException::class
    )
    fun getText(request: HttpServletRequest, response: ServletResponse) {
        render(Renderers.PLAIN, request, response)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, InterruptedException::class)
    private fun render(renderer: IRenderer, request: HttpServletRequest, response: ServletResponse) {
        val stubLength = getStubLength(request)
        val outputStream: ServletOutputStream = response.outputStream
        renderer.renderStub(stubLength, outputStream)
        renderInfiniteContent(renderer, outputStream)
    }

    private fun getStubLength(request: HttpServletRequest): Int {
        val userAgent: String = request.getHeader("User-Agent") ?: return 0
        if (userAgent.contains("Chrome")) {
            return 1024
        }
        return if (userAgent.contains("Firefox")) {
            1024
        } else 0
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, InterruptedException::class)
    private fun renderInfiniteContent(renderer: IRenderer, outputStream: ServletOutputStream) {
        while (true) {
            for (line in lines) {
                renderer.renderLine(line, outputStream)
                Thread.sleep(5000)
            }
        }
    }

    private interface IRenderer {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun renderStub(length: Int, outputStream: ServletOutputStream?)

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun renderLine(line: String?, outputStream: ServletOutputStream?)
    }

    private enum class Renderers : IRenderer {
        HTML {
            private val HTML_PREFIX = "<!-- "
            private val HTML_SUFFIX = " -->"
            private val HTML_PREFIX_SUFFIX_LENGTH = HTML_PREFIX.length + HTML_SUFFIX.length

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun renderStub(length: Int, outputStream: ServletOutputStream?) {
                outputStream?.print(HTML_PREFIX)
                for (i in 0 until length - HTML_PREFIX_SUFFIX_LENGTH) {
                    outputStream?.write('\u0020'.code)
                }
                outputStream?.print(HTML_SUFFIX)
                outputStream?.flush()
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun renderLine(line: String?, outputStream: ServletOutputStream?) {
                outputStream?.print(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(line!!, "UTF-8"))
                outputStream?.print("<br/>")
            }


        },
        PLAIN {
            private val ZERO_WIDTH_CHAR = '\u200B'
            private val bom = byteArrayOf(0xEF.toByte(), 0xBB.toByte(), 0xBF.toByte())

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun renderStub(length: Int, outputStream: ServletOutputStream?) {
                outputStream?.write(bom)
                for (i in 0 until length) {
                    outputStream?.write(ZERO_WIDTH_CHAR.code)
                }
                outputStream?.flush()
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun renderLine(line: String?, outputStream: ServletOutputStream?) {
                outputStream?.println(line)
                outputStream?.flush()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write the consumer side that read the stream text from producer and write it just like the producer app for another application(it seems doing hand-off). Can you help me please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.